# Making an object follow another objects x position

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In my code, I'm trying to make so that a square follows where ever the user touches and holds, but when I tried coding it, the square goes randomly everywhere and doesn't follow where the user held their finger. Can someone help me modify this code to make it work?

```
 override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var speedOfTouch = CGFloat(30)

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if location.x < CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) {
            square.position.x <= speedOfTouch
            square.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -10 , dy: 0))



        }
        else {
            square.position.x >= speedOfTouch
            square.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 10, dy: 0))
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare the touch's location to the square's current location rather than the center (which I'm guessing is where the square's first position was)

With physics:

```
 override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var speedOfTouch = CGFloat(30)

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if location.x < square.position.x {
            square.position.x <= speedOfTouch
            square.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -10 , dy: 0))



        }
        else {
            square.position.x >= speedOfTouch
            square.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 10, dy: 0))
        }

    }
}
```

Without physics:

```
 override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var speedOfTouch = CGFloat(30)

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        square.position = CGPointMake(location.x, square.position.y)
    }
}
```

Comment: But whenever I do this the square slides around everywhere.

Comment: Then just set the square's position instead of sliding it with an impulse.

Comment: The square just slides to the left if the user lets go though.

Comment: Check the updated post. Not really sure what you were trying to do with the speedOfTouch thing, so I just took it out.

Comment: Wow thanks Kendel, you really helped me. Thanks!! ;D

Comment: Yep no problem. If it is the answer to the problem be sure to hit that check mark :D

Comment: If you have questions I suggest posting them just on stack overflow. I usually can help answer or someone else will.

Comment: It's a very long one, do you think you could help me?

Comment: Again, I have no clue so if you have another question, then you should post another question. The comments of an answer is not the place for help on a different question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735022/error-spawning-sprites-in-swift-spritekit