# Error spawning sprites in Swift/SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm having a problem in my code. When my obstacles come down forever, the "path" where the square is supposed to go through is sometime off the screen, and not positioned where I want it. I want the path to be between 1/4 of the screen width. I think the error is somewhere in the width and randomXPos constants. How can I fix this? (If you want a further explanation I can explain more.)

```
func addObstacles2() {

    let obstacle2A = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Obstacle")
    let obstacle2B = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Obstacle")

    let width = UInt32(self.frame.size.width / 5)
    let randomXPos = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(width)))
    let gapWidth = square.size.width * 2

    let moveDown2A = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -self.size.width, duration: 2.5)
    let repeatAction2A = SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveDown2A)
    let removeObstacle2A = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let moveAndRemove2A = SKAction.sequence([repeatAction2A, removeObstacle2A])

    obstacle2A.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: 300)
    obstacle2A.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + obstacle2A.size.width / 2 + gapWidth / 2 + randomXPos, self.frame.size.height * 2)
    obstacle2A.zPosition = 40
    obstacle2A.runAction(moveAndRemove2A)
    self.addChild(obstacle2A)


    let moveDown2B = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -self.size.width, duration: 2.5)
    let repeatAction2B = SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveDown2B)
    let removeObstacle2B = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let moveAndRemove2B = SKAction.sequence([repeatAction2B, removeObstacle2B])

    obstacle2B.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: 300)
    obstacle2B.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - obstacle2B.size.width / 2 - gapWidth / 2 + randomXPos, self.frame.size.height * 2)
    obstacle2B.zPosition = 40
    obstacle2B.runAction(moveAndRemove2B)
    self.addChild(obstacle2B)

}
```

(Please note: I have a function that already makes the obstacles spawn forever.)

Comment: In other words I want a leading and trailing position in the width constant

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it looks like you're subtracting a little too much from the Object2B's x position.

The first important thing to realize is that `self.frame.size.width` doesn't return the width of what the user sees on his device. It will return a little extra, actually, because sprite kit is configured by default to have a set coordinate system in order to allow the developer to hard-code in the coordinates and see the same thing on each device. (It's the scale mode that the scene has by default - `SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill`).

So, if we take a look mathematically at what you are doing, we see that you are starting  out in the middle of the view, (x coordinate 512, I believe). Then, you subtract half of that value, putting you at x coordinate 256 (getting close already to going off the screen). Then you subtract even more, thus resulting in some of the nodes being off the screen.

There isn't a problem with your random value. It's that with your default coordinate system your not seeing some of them. Try hard-coding the values in

Comment: Could you give me some examples on how to do this? (I'm a beginner)

Comment: Yeah so instead of placing nodes using `self.frame.size`, use actual numerical values. I'm not sure what the gapWidth variable is equal to so I can't give you any precise calculations (also it would be better for you to handle those things on your own to get a better feel for it). You could do some testing on your own to figure out at what point does the square exit the screen as well...

Comment: ok. give me the value of your gapWidth variable (square.size.width/2). Ill show you the calculations

Comment: It changes for each device but it's about 150 pixels wide.

Comment: hmm.... so you don't have a constant size? SpriteKit is meant to use constant values that it then converts to pixels through its own algorithms. Normally we don't specify in pixels but rather use "points" that are relative to each other by the scale that the device's pixels dictate.

Comment: but regardless, lets say that the gapWidth is equal to 150. Now you calculate Obstacle2B's position: position = (512 - 512 - 75 + randomX). see?? if your randomX is between 0 and approx. 205 (equivalent of dividing 1024 (the scene width) by 5 then that means your position is between -75 and 130...... and negative positions will clearly bring your node off the screen

Comment: what you need to do is make a sample node thats just a plain black box and just play with the coordinates until you get what you want. see what happens you set the node at 0, at 100, at 200. Then adjust randomXpos to have the range you need and use just that variable to set your x position